# Does bash profile have protected keys that are unassignable?

Tags: bash

I am running OSX 10.10.3 are there any protected alphabetic keys that cant be assigned? For instance "L".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **some key combinations that are quazi-protected** in the sense they come pre-assigned, but even then they **can be overwritten using 'sudo'**. I know that “L” in particular is not protected. It can be considered a matter of preference, but I personally wouldn’t make a habit of overwriting common ones such as “LS” for example.

Comment: Thanks, going to look into pseudo more do you know of any good resources?

Comment: Not off the top of my head but just do a quick google search

Comment: Thanks again for the help